# Android DAWG implementation

Tags: android, algorithm, dawg

In my application I need to work with dictionary, what have a lot of words(110 000), so I decided to use trie, but loading of trie cost 9 seconds every time. And this is much a lot even for my emulator. Recently I have read about DAWG(Direct Acyclinc Word Graph) or Minimal Acyclinc Finite State Automaton [DAWG wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton) what will affect load performance but I can't find a good explanation of algorithm of creating DAWG or Trie to DAWG algorithm. Also I can't find any example, written on java, so I ask you for help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a little too late for your needs, but for the sake of others who may find themselves here, have a look at [MDAG](https://github.com/klawson88/MDAG), created and maintained by yours truly :) .

Comment: and here is my repo, which contains double-chained trie and that trie can be easily converted to respective DAWG https://github.com/MikeHerasimov/Trie

Comment: also I provided serialization/deserialization algorithms

Comment: and finally my trie/dawg are both internationalized

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm reading Hopcroft's book named "Introduction to automata theory" it has explanation of many automaton algorithms including automaton minimization(at 4.4.3 chapter)

link to this book 
[John Hopcoft "Introduction to automata theory"](http://www.pmfst.unist.hr/~milica/Matem_teorija_r/MTR_web/Introduction%20To%20Automata%20Theory.pdf)

Also there are [JFLAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFLAP), which can minimize finize state machine.